# Can pickled pepper oil be used as cooking oil?

Tags: substitutions, oil, pickling, pepper

I have about a half jar of pure pickled pepper oil as I have recently used up all of the peppers. The oil is a strange translucent color of yellow; I'm imagining a cup of highlighter fluid (if there is such a thing).

I'm wondering if this oil is okay to use for cooking oil or as a substitute for other oils in other dishes, or am I better off throwing it out if it cannot serve as an appropriate substitute whatsoever.

Comment: It may have a low smoke point and not be well suited for frying, but it should be food grade oil and if you like the taste, I'd say go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use it for anything other than deep frying or high temperature frying. It would be great for anything that requires oil but not cooking, like hummus.